# Javascript does not call function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a game that goes from the start screen to the loading screen when the user clicks. I discovered that I can't even call the function.

```
function startScreen() { // gets called from begining
  // code that works fine
  canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    loading();
  }, false);
}
```

The code looks fine but when I run it it does not work. The link to the project is: https://jsfiddle.net/starlite_developer/pqvcL187/783/

Comment: Is `canvas` element present in DOM when  `startScreen` is invoked ?

Comment: It's actually working - add a console.log('loading') to your loading function

Comment: What is  supposed to happen when someone clicks on the canvas? It seems to call the function but does nothing.